# C# method definition error AbrKeyStore

Tags: .net

Anyone knows the exact explanation for this error. Attached is the screenshot and the project file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6-jE4sMDIpcSm4zU25aV08zZ1U/view?usp=sharing

Error

[image]

Comment: If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Ive actually had a screenshot. (Click to view error screenshot) above. or this URL https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUCoD.png

Comment: project file is also attached. or to this URL https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6-jE4sMDIpcSm4zU25aV08zZ1U/view

Comment: private static X509Certificate2 GetAUSkeyClientCertificate()
 {
  var keyStore = AbrKeyStore.GetInstance(new FileInfo(AUSkey_Keystore_Location));

  using (var pwd = GetPasswordString())
  {
   X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = keyStore.GetPrivateKey(AUSkey_Alias, pwd);
   return clientCertificate;
  }

 }